# Issue iterating a collection using Streams and Lambdas expressions of Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm starting to learn about Java 8 streams and lambdas expressions.
I want to iterate a collection but I'm getting a compilation error. I understand why is happening this error but I don't know how to get rid of it. Below the code:

```
 List<TT021OrderDetails> entitiesList =BeanAdapter.getInstance().transformToEntityList(
            TT021OrderDetails.class, positionsList);

    entitiesList=(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entitiesList))?entitiesList.stream().forEach(orderDetail->orderDetail.setOrderHeader(entity)):null;
```

So what I need is to iterate the collection entitiesList (if it is not null), and for each entity I want to set the value of one attribute of the object, and then return the collection already filled.

Well,I wanted to do that using the new API for java 8 but I'm getting a compilation error saying "Incompatible types, required List, found void", which basically is telling me that the terminal method forEach does not return anything, however it is expecting to to return a List as declared in the sentence.

If the forEach method return void, how can iterate the list and return the list already filled?
Any idea how to solve this, or  other way arund to do it? (Besides of course the typical for(TT021OrderDetails orderDetail:entitiesList ){...} )

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why null if empty? Why not just return an empty collection? What is more, `forEach()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use peek instead of forEach and have a `collect` as the terminal operation to get the list :

```
entitiesList=(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entitiesList))?entitiesList.stream().peek(orderDetail->orderDetail.setOrderHeader(entity)).collect(Collectors.toList()):null;
```

However, since you are not changing the list (you are simply iterating over the `entitiesList` and calling a method for each element), this entire assignment is not necessary.

Just write :

```
if (entitiesList != null) {
    entitiesList.forEach(orderDetail->orderDetail.setOrderHeader(entity));
}
```

You don't even need the Stream.

Answer (score 0):

like fge mentioned [forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) returns void. To achive what you are looking for use [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).

```
newList = yourList.stream().map(o -> {do whatever you want}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

For each returns void. You can simply iterate through a stream, without assigning results to a list.

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(entitiesList)){
   entitiesList.stream().forEach(orderDetail->orderDetail.setOrderHeader(entity))
}
```

Tutorial on JDK8 forEach:

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_from_a_for